# AspNet Core 1.1. referencing .net 4.6 project fails on runtime

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1. web application and I have successfully referenced it to a .NET 4.6 class library.

When a call is made from one of the web application's controllers to one of the public methods of .NET 4.6 class library I am getting the following exception:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Any ideas, how I can correct that?

Comment: Is your Core application running on the full framework? .NET Core cannot reference a full framework library. You either need to use the full framework for your Core application, or your library needs to target a compatible version of .NET Standard (which I believe is 1.4 for compatibility with .NET Core).

Comment: Actually any version of Standard works with .NET Core 1.X, however, you need at least 1.3 for the dependency on .NET 4.6. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: @ChrisPratt That was the case. The Core application was not running on the full framework. When I changed it, it worked fine. Thanks